# How to use Leibniz integral rule If f goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If $F(t)$ is defined as follows:

$$
F(t) = \int_0^t \frac{y(\tau)}{\sqrt{t-\tau}}d\tau
$$

I want to calculate $F'(t)$ using Libniz integral rule. Use $f(t,\tau)$ to denote the part in the integration:
$$
f(t,\tau) = \frac{y(\tau)}{\sqrt{t-\tau}}
$$

I know that $y(t)$ is a finite value, so $f(t,t)$ is $+\infty$,
use following formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we would have the result equals to $+\infty - \infty$, which is not what I want.

$$
{\frac {d}{dx}}\left(\int _{0}^{x}f(x,t)dt\right)=f{\big (}x,x{\big )}+\int _{0}^{x}{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}f(x,t)dt
$$

it looks like in this case Leibniz integral rule is not applicable.

Is there a way to find $F'(t)$?

Comment: The Leibniz rules is applicable, the function is ill-behaved only over a set of measure zero.  For instance, take $y(\tau)=C$ a constant, the integral is $F(t)=2C\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Yes, the result is finite, but how can I get $F'(t)$ when $y(\tau)$  is an arbitrary smooth and bounded function?

Answer (score 1):

First use integration by parts: $$F(t)=2y(t)\sqrt{t}+2\int_0^t y'(\tau)\sqrt{t-\tau}\,d\tau.$$ Now the Leibniz integral rule is perfectly applicable.

Another approach is to substitute $\tau=tx$ and get $$F(t)=\sqrt{t}\int_0^1\frac{y(tx)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx.$$ Again, the derivative is easy to take now (and you can bring $\tau$ back then).

Comment: thank you very much